# reuseable binded expression value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

says I've a complex nested json / js objects, which within there's `"username":"John"`, and somewhere in my html I had retrieved it by doing for example like this

```
<li ng-repeat="user in userJsonData">
{{user.username}}
</li>
```

and later on I want to reuse the `{{user.username}}`, for sure I don't want to use `ng-repeat` to just retrieve a single piece of value. so how can I reuse bound value again in view (html)?

Comment: Just to make it clear: you want to display single `username` attribute of an object that is in `userJsonData` array? Or do you want to display `username` of all users in `userJsonData`?

Comment: I suggest you to store it in service. The service as Singleton and doesn't have scope so after storing you can load it in any controller.

Comment: @package I don't get u, I want to use user.username more than one times in view, and I've no problem getting it display, just that I'm curious why I need to go into userJsonData again using ng-repeat.

Comment: You don't have to duplicate ngRepeat. The only problem is, neither I nor angularJs knows which user do you have in mind. Is it first user from array (`userJsonData[0]`)? Or second (`userJsonData[1]`?) Or maybe the last one (`userJsonData[userJsonData.length - 1]`)? The `user` in `<li ng-repeat="user in userJsonData">` is only accessible within boundaries of that particular `<li></li>`, this is called the `scope`.